# Question about interpretation of a fixed effects model

Tags: regression, econometrics, interpretation, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to see the impact of a group of similarly-minded policies and programs which were introduced at various dates in various Canadian provinces on a measure of student satisfaction.

I plan to create an annual province-level index reflecting the extent of these similarly-minded policies to serve as my explanatory variable. I have annual province-level data on student satisfaction. I was thinking to use a fixed effects model with several controls to capture the relationship between the policy index score and student satisfaction. Thus, my basic model would look like

$Y_{it}=\alpha_i+\beta X_{it}+\epsilon_{it}$ for province i in year t.

I am also interested in seeing the impact of having these policies in one province, province $j$, in particular.

To do this, I am thinking to use the following logic:

From the FE model, I will ultimately find that for any province i in any year t, on average, a one point decrease in the index score (i.e. a one-unit decrease in $X_{it}$) will result in a change of $\beta$ in $Y_{it}$. Suppose, for example, that in 2017, province $j$'s index score is 15. Then if province $j$ had none of these indexed policies (i.e. its index score was 0), $Y_{it}$ would change by $-15\beta$. Thus, the impact of these policies in province $j$ in year 2017 on the dependent variable was $-15\beta$.

Does this reasoning make sense? Am I interpreting the $\beta$ coefficient in the FE model correctly?

Comment: Just to be clear for myself and others: $\epsilon_{it}$ is taken to be independent and identically distributed *despite* the panel design. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you can specify your basic model as a linear regression model which relates Satisfaction (outcome variable) to the predictors Index and Province. In this basic model, Index and Province would be allowed to interact, since it is likely that the relationship between Index and Satisfaction would be different across provinces. If necessary, the model specification could allow for residual correlation among the model errors (e.g., AR(1)).

The basic model could be expanded to allow for control variables - if the effect of these control variables on satisfaction may be different across provinces, the interactions between these control variables and Province could be introduced in the model.

Comment: Thank you for your input! So if I understand correctly, you're suggesting to just run an OLS regression with a province dummy? Should I add a time dummy as well to account for differences by year?

Comment: Also, wouldn't the interaction term give me the impact of the index score in a province relative to the base province, rather than the absolute impact in that province?

Comment: Yes, I suggested running an OLS regression initially - however, since your data are collected over time, you may have correlation among the model residuals for some or all provinces. So you may need to consider GLS regression if you determine that to be the case (GLS = Generalized Least Squares Regression).

Comment: If you are interested in differences by year (not just by province), then you would include a 3-way interaction term in your model between Index, Year and Province. (Year would be treated as a categorical variable, with levels such as "2018", "2019", etc.)

Comment: If you use dummy variable coding for Year and Province, it is possible to work your way back from the relative effect of Index on Satisfaction in one Province compared to the baseline Province (in a Particular Year) to the absolute effect of interest. The absolute effects you need will be linear combinations of the relative effects listed in the model, so you'll be able to estimate them by setting up appropriate linear contrasts.